# Stop WebSphere enterprise applications from applicatoin

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-7

Good time. Can you tell me, how i can stop application in websphere from my application? I'm doing some changes in application in listener when application was start. And if my changes not apply -> application must stop.

My method is called from listener.

Comment: Are you asking: (1) how to stop appA from appB, or (2) how to prevent appA from fully starting if it detects that it should not start?

Comment: second, how to prevent appA from fully starting if it detects that it should not start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

1. Add an EJB `@Startup @Singleton` to the application, and throw an exception from `@PostConstruct` if the application should not start.
2. Add a `ServletContainerInitializer` or `ServletContextListener` to the application, and throw an exception if the application should not start.
3. Use the WebSphere-specific `AppStartUp` interface, and return false if the application should not start.